# Remove tcategorypanel border

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

How can you remove the border from TCategoryPanel and TCategoryPanelGroup in XE3?

Tried this and didn't work:

```
type
   TCategoryPanel =  class (Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCategoryPanel)
protected
   procedure  CreateParams ( var  Params: TCreateParams);  override ;
end ;

procedure  TCategoryPanel.CreateParams ( var  Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  Inherited ;
  Params.Style:= Params.Style  and  not  WS_BORDER;
end ;
```

Comment: Found how to remove the one from the Panel but not the PanelGroup. The panel apparently has an unpublised BevelOuter which I set to bvNone and it worked.  Looked for a border setting for the group but doesn't have one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `TCategoryPanel` you need to set the protected property `BevelOuter` to `bvNone`.

For `TCategoryPanelGroup` you can indeed remove the border in `CreateParams`. Like so:

```
Params.Style := Params.Style and (not WS_BORDER);
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: For some reason, still can't get this to work even with the (not WS_BORDER)  But, I can live with this border.  The panel 3d was killing me tho.  Thanks.

Comment: I added a screenshot to prove that I had succeeded

Comment: I see... would TStyleManager override this?

Comment: Would the use of VCL styles be relevant? Er yes it would. That would be a completely different question! But since you are on XE, you can't be doing that. But standard Window themes are fine. My test uses them.