# How to turn off the border on TCategoryPanelGroup

Tags: delphi

It has no Borderwidth or BorderStyle properties !

I noticed it was derived from TscrollingWInControl which does have a Borderwidth property but gets hidden by TCategoryPanelGroup, so I derived and exposed the property and set it to zero but that had no effect.

I suppose it needs a Borderstyle set to bsnone but there is no such property in the hierarchy.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe by giving this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004200/remove-tcategorypanel-border) a try?

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick !